# How can I add every product as a new item into cart

Tags: php, magento

If we talk about default functionality of Magento . when we add product into cart it added as an item and when we add same product into cart, it just update the quantity of product for same item instead of adding a new item with new quantity . now i want to add every product into cart as a new item. or is there any observer event to do so which i can use for those product , who have specific attribute set .

Example i have to type of product first one are created with default attribute set and second one are created with new attribute set.

now i want when customer add a product two times into cart who has default attribute set the cart show updated quantity without adding new item.

and when customer add a product two time into cart who has new attribute set ,cart must be display those product as separate items without updating the quantity.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is located in Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::_addCatalogProduct(). You can see that this method calls $this->getItemByProduct(); So You need to rewrite Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::getItemByProduct() to solve the issue.